# Hide ImageButton for first and last

Tags: java, android

Currently I build learning app for children. This app learn alphabet from "A" to "Z". If click the next button the alphabet will switch from A to B, B to C, and etc. But, I want if "A" the previous button (ImageButton) will be hide and if "Z" the next button will be hide.

```
public class ScrBelajarHuruf extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView txtHuruf;
    ImageButton btnAudioHuruf, btnNextHuruf, btnPreviousHuruf;
    
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    
    int counterHurufList;
    int counter = 0;
    int counterAudioHurufList;
    
    int[] stringHurufList = {
            R.string.huruf_a,
            R.string.huruf_b,
            R.string.huruf_c,
            R.string.huruf_d,
            R.string.huruf_e,
            R.string.huruf_f,
            R.string.huruf_g,
            R.string.huruf_h,
            R.string.huruf_i,
            R.string.huruf_j,
            R.string.huruf_k,
            R.string.huruf_l,
            R.string.huruf_m,
            R.string.huruf_n,
            R.string.huruf_o,
            R.string.huruf_p,
            R.string.huruf_q,
            R.string.huruf_r,
            R.string.huruf_s,
            R.string.huruf_t,
            R.string.huruf_u,
            R.string.huruf_v,
            R.string.huruf_w,
            R.string.huruf_x,
            R.string.huruf_y,
            R.string.huruf_z,
    };
    
    int[] rawAudioHurufList = {
            R.raw.a,
            R.raw.b,
            R.raw.c,
            R.raw.d,
            R.raw.e,
            R.raw.f,
            R.raw.g,
            R.raw.h,
            R.raw.i,
            R.raw.j,
            R.raw.k,
            R.raw.l,
            R.raw.m,
            R.raw.n,
            R.raw.o,
            R.raw.p,
            R.raw.q,
            R.raw.r,
            R.raw.s,
            R.raw.t,
            R.raw.u,
            R.raw.v,
            R.raw.w,
            R.raw.x,
            R.raw.y,
            R.raw.z,

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scr_belajar_huruf);

        txtHuruf = findViewById(R.id.txtHuruf);
        btnAudioHuruf = findViewById(R.id.btnAudioHuruf);
        btnNextHuruf = findViewById(R.id.btnNextHuruf);
        btnPreviousHuruf = findViewById(R.id.btnPreviousHuruf);
        
        btnAudioHuruf.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnNextHuruf.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnPreviousHuruf.setOnClickListener(this);
        
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a);
        
        mediaPlayer.start();
    if(counterHurufList == 0) {
        btnPreviousHuruf.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        
        int id = view.getId();
        
        if(id == R.id.btnNextHuruf && counterHurufList < stringHurufList.length - 1 && counterAudioHurufList < rawAudioHurufList.length - 1) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            counterHurufList++;
            counterAudioHurufList++;
        } else if (id == R.id.btnPreviousHuruf  && counterHurufList > 0 && counterAudioHurufList > 0) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            counterHurufList--;
            counterAudioHurufList--;
        }
        
        txtHuruf.setText(stringHurufList[counterHurufList]);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, rawAudioHurufList[counterAudioHurufList]);
        mediaPlayer.start();


    }

}
```

I tried with

```
if(counterHurufList == 0) {
        btnPreviousHuruf.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

But give the previous button hide from "A" to "Z"

[image: This is what I tried]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't run this code so hopefully it works, but here are my thoughts from what you've shown:

1. You only perform the check to hide the button in `onCreate`, so it'll only do it once when the activity is created
2. You only hide the go back button
3. You only hide the button, and don't try to make it visible again

In your `onCreate` method, remove the check

```java
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scr_belajar_huruf);

        txtHuruf = findViewById(R.id.txtHuruf);
        btnAudioHuruf = findViewById(R.id.btnAudioHuruf);
        btnNextHuruf = findViewById(R.id.btnNextHuruf);
        btnPreviousHuruf = findViewById(R.id.btnPreviousHuruf);
        
        btnAudioHuruf.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnNextHuruf.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnPreviousHuruf.setOnClickListener(this);
        
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a);
        
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

And in your `onClick` method, make sure you address all the points I mentioned above:

```java
    public void onClick(View view) {
        
        int id = view.getId();
        
        if(id == R.id.btnNextHuruf && counterHurufList < stringHurufList.length - 1 && counterAudioHurufList < rawAudioHurufList.length - 1) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            counterHurufList++;
            counterAudioHurufList++;
        } else if (id == R.id.btnPreviousHuruf  && counterHurufList > 0 && counterAudioHurufList > 0) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            counterHurufList--;
            counterAudioHurufList--;
        }
        
        txtHuruf.setText(stringHurufList[counterHurufList]);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, rawAudioHurufList[counterAudioHurufList]);
        mediaPlayer.start();

        // New parts
        btnPreviousHuruf.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnNextHuruf.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (counterHurufList == 0)
            btnPreviousHuruf.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if (counterHurufList == 25)
            btnNextHuruf.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

Obviously modify however you like, but ensure that you meet the three criteria :)

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (stringHurufList[counterHurufList]) {
  case "A":
    btnPreviousHuruf.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    break;
  case "Z":
    btnNextHuruf.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    break;
  default:
    btnPreviousHuruf.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btnNextHuruf.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

> But give the previous button hide from "A" to "Z"

Its because you forgot to return btn visibility to VISIBLE.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an instance variable let's say `int currentPosition = 0;`. First time make previous button invisible `prevBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` Use this single position for both next and previous functionality. Like:

```
                public void onClick(View view) {

                int id = view.getId();

                if(id == R.id.btnNextHuruf) {
                    currentPosition++;
                    prevBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (currentPosition == 25){
                        nextBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                    }

                    //counterHurufList++;
                    //counterAudioHurufList++;
                } else if (id == R.id.btnPreviousHuruf) {
                    currentPosition--;
                    nextBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   if (currentPosition == 0){
                       prevBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                       mediaPlayer.stop();
                   }
                }

                txtHuruf.setText(stringHurufList[currentPosition]);
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, rawAudioHurufList[currentPosition]);
                mediaPlayer.start();


            }
```